# I have to use this formula to prove that the ycoordinate of a stationary point is is an integer without a calculator

Tags: derivatives

I have no idea how to, could you guys show me?
$$\cosh^2(x) - \sinh^2(x)=1$$
I used the following to prove this true:
$$\cosh x =\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$
$$\sinh x =\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
Now I have to use this formula to prove that the ycoordinate of the stationary point of following function is true:
$$f(x) = 6 \sinh x + \cosh^2(x)$$
So i found the x-value of the stationary point which is $x = sinh^{-1}(-3)$ and subbed it in. I got:
$$y = 6\sinh(\sinh^{-1}(-3)) + \cosh^2(\sinh^{-1}(-3))$$
$$y = -18 + \cosh^2(\sinh^{-1}(-3))$$
I don't know where to go from there and how do i apply the formula to this?

Comment: Numbers are not "true", so it would be helpful if you could edit your post to state what it is you want to prove about the $y$-coordinate of the stationary point.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the stationary point. You know that $\sinh x = -3$. You know that $\cosh^2 x = 1 + \sinh^2 x$. You don't need anything else to figure out what $y = 6\sinh x + \cosh^2 x$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by the formula, $$f(x)=\sinh^2x+6\sinh x+1=\left(\sinh x\right)^2+6\sinh x+1.$$ Can you take it from there?

P.S.: You can actually use this to determine the $x$-coordinate of the stationary point, instead, with no need for differentiation.